# Kotlin - Issue in opening Soft Keyboard for the CustomFonts

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, truetype

I have created below class to set the custom fonts or any **otf** fonts in my normal EditText.
Am working with kotlin and created below class for the generalization of using CustomEditText.

I have added fonts file in asset and created below class named **CustomEditText**:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.TypedArray
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText

class CustomEditText : AppCompatEditText{

constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null) {
    init(null)
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0) {
    init(attrs)
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr
) {
    init(attrs)
}

private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
    CustomEditText(context, attrs, 0)
}

/**
 * @param context:This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by Android Operating System.
 * @param attrs:A collection of attributes, as found associated with a tag in an XML document.
 * @param defStyle:
 */
fun CustomEditText(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet?,
    defStyle: Int
) {
    try {
        val a: TypedArray =
            context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditText, defStyle, 0)
        val customEnumValue: CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType =
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.fromId(
                a.getInt(
                    R.styleable.CustomEditText_font_type,
                    0
                )
            )
        a.recycle()
        typeface = when (customEnumValue) {
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.BLACK ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-Black.otf") // BrandonTextBlack().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.BLACK_ITALIC ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-BlackItalic.otf") // BrandonTextBlackItalic().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.BOLD ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-Bold.otf") // BrandonTextBold().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.BOLD_ITALIC ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-BoldItalic.otf") // BrandonTextBoldItalic().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.LIGHT ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-Light.otf") // BrandonTextBoldItalic().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.LIGHT_ITALIC ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-LightItalic.otf") // BrandonTextBoldItalic().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.MEDIUM ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-Medium.otf") // BrandonTextBoldItalic().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.MEDIUM_ITALIC ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-MediumItalic.otf") // BrandonTextBoldItalic().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.REGULAR ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-Regular.otf") // BrandonTextBoldItalic().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.REGULAR_ITALIC ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-RegularItalic.otf") // BrandonTextBoldItalic().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.THIN ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-Thin.otf") // BrandonTextBoldItalic().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
            CustomEnumBrandonNew.CustomFontType.THIN_ITALIC ->
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "BrandonText-ThinItalic.otf") // BrandonTextBoldItalic().getInstance(context)?.getTypeFace()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
}
```

Before it, I have also created seperate classes i.e. **BrandonTextBlack**, **BrandonTextBlackItalic**, **BrandonTextBold** etc. as below :

```
class BrandonTextBold{

private var instance: BrandonTextBold? = null
private var typeface: Typeface? = null

fun getInstance(context: Context): BrandonTextBold? {
    synchronized(BrandonTextBold::class.java) {
        if (instance == null) {
            typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.resources.assets, "BrandonText-Bold.otf")
        }
        return instance
    }
}

fun getTypeFace(): Typeface? {
    return typeface
}

}
```

Now, in layout xml file, using it as below :

```
<CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_mobile_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_40"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable_round_button_transperent"
            android:hint="@string/str_hint_enter_your_mobile_number"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="number|phone"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorHintAndBorder"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_8"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_8"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_15"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_15"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_dimen_20"
            app:font_type="regular" />
```

Here notice that I have used **app:font_type="regular"**. So, I can have normal font type in my edittext. It's done.

But, the issue is softkeyboard not opening when I press or try to write something in it.

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use default style as EditText style in your all constructors instead of 0

From

```
 constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0) {
        init(attrs)
    }
```

To

```
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.editTextStyle) {
        init(attrs)
    }
```